# Are there any free Online Urdu Qur'ans?

Tags: quran, quran-translation, english

I should like to learn Urdu, but I am having problems trying to find an online Urdu Qur'an -- I know of no other book that I can pick and be sure that most of the words are translated about as closely as possible across langauges. There will be some quirks at the translator's tastes, but all-in-all, the majority should be comfortably the same.

Comment: What do you want quran translation in urdu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most websites and apps offering multi-lingual translations should have an option for Urdu.

For example:

[Legacy Quran.com](http://legacy.quran.com) has an Urdu translation.
[AlQuran.info](http://al-quran.info) has eight Urdu translations.
[SearchTruth](http://www.searchtruth.com/chapter_display.php?chapter=1&translator=17) has an Urdu translation.
[Hamari-Web](https://www.hamariweb.com/islam/online-Quran/) has three Urdu translations.

Archive.org has scanned copies of several print editions, which you can optionally download as pdf:

[One](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaShahRafiUlDeen-ShahRafiUddeenDhelvi#page/n0/mode/2up)
[Two](https://archive.org/details/001SurahAlFatihah_201508)
[Three](https://archive.org/details/UrduAndArabicQuranTranslation_201507)
[Four](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaJalandhari-FatheMuhammedJalandhri#page/n0/mode/2up)
[Five](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaFaiqUlBayan-ShahRafiUddeenDhelvi#page/n0/mode/2up)
[Six](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/AlQuranTarjamaThanvi-AshrafAliThanvi#page/n0/mode/2up)
[Seven](https://archive.org/stream/TaraajimAlQuran-Urdu/TafseeriTarjamaEQuranMajeed-MuhammedRafeeq#page/n0/mode/2up)

Answer (score -1):

In this page there is a Hindi translation, I hope it will be helpful.
https://www.khalidapps.com/quran/?lang=hi