# Where i can download Hindi/Urdu translation of Quran

Tags: quran, quran-translation, reading-quran

I'm looking for Quran translation either in hindi/urdu  which i can download in my mobile phone

and listen to it often.

I don't want to visit to any page to listen to it, basically i want to download into my phone so that whenever i feel or i'm  lonely i will listen to it.

I heard there are many translation, found these translation to be good

1. Sahi International
2. Abdullah Yusuf Ali
3. Pickthall

Please help me to find, thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of : [Are there any free Online Urdu Qur'ans](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39117/are-there-any-free-online-urdu-qurans?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

Islam: The Noble Quran (https://goo.gl/prmwod)
It contain saheeeh international ,ahmad raza khan , shakir ,hilali and pickthall, and urdu and hindi translation as well.
I also contain audio of different qaris
Highly recomended

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

first of all thanks to @ahmad butt,

I have found the following links after googling, which i can download

**HINDI**

i have found very good translation of the Quran with the voice of Sheikh Sudais  https://archive.org/details/hindi-meal which i can download.

even i found

**URDU**(Sahi International)

with the voice of Sheikh Sudais, Sheikh Shuraim

https://archive.org/details/quran-hindi-urdu-sahi-international-shuraim-sudais